# How to trigger a function on one instance if we are using *ngFor in angular 4

Tags: angular, object, click, ngfor

**HTML**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    Angular Material 2 App
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="basic-container">  
     <div *ngFor="let item of names">
       <p>{{item}} {{flag}} {{str}}</p>
       <button (click)='enable()'>Display</button><br>
      <mat-spinner *ngIf="flag" strokeWidth="3" [diameter]="20"></mat-spinner> 
       </div>  
    <span class="version-info">Current build: {{version.full}}</span>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {VERSION} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { 
  version = VERSION;
  names = ["hello" , "hIII" , "BYE"];
  flag:boolean=false;
  str='Ar';

  enable() :void {
    this.flag= true;
    this.str = "Arpit";
  }
}
```

In the above code on click of display button I want to show the spinner on that particular div only not on all but since I am using `*ngFor` the function is getting called every where.

[stackbliz url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-progress-spinner-6jqaqn)

Comment: did you check my answer? accepted answer might solved your problem but that's not good approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve it by adding index in *ngFor
[working link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-progress-spinner-k4otyg?file=app/app.component.html)

**In Component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent { 
version = VERSION;
names = ["hello" , "hIII" , "BYE"];
flag:boolean=false;
index : number =0;

 toggle(i) :void {
    if(this.index == i && this.flag){
    this.index =null;
   }else{
     this.flag  = true;
     this.index = i;
   }
 }
```

**In Html**

```
 <mat-toolbar color="primary">
  Angular Material 2 App
   </mat-toolbar>
 <div class="basic-container">  
   <div *ngFor="let item of names;let i= index">
   <p>{{item}}</p>  
   <button (click)="toggle(i)">Display</button><br>
  <mat-spinner *ngIf="i == index && flag" strokeWidth="3" [diameter]="20"> 
    </mat-spinner> 
   </div>  
<span class="version-info">Current build: {{version.full}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `index` inside for loop. 
if i understood your question you need something like this

**In Component:**

```
<div class="basic-container">  
 <div *ngFor="let item of names;let i=index;">
   <p>{{item}}</p>
   <button (click)='enable(i+1)'>Display</button><br>
  <mat-spinner *ngIf="newIndex==(i+1)" strokeWidth="3" [diameter]="20"></mat-spinner> 
   </div>  
</div>
```

In typescript need to initialize variable:

```
newIndex: any;
enable(index) :void {
   if(this.newIndex !== index){
      this.newIndex = index;
   }else{
      this.newIndex = this.names.length + 1;
   }
}
```

Here is working Example: [angular-material2-progress-spinner-for-each-button-click](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-progress-spinner-9zpd5s)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is, modify your Array of items. It should have flag, str or any other key as you want. Pass item on button click and modify object according to your need.

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of names">
    <p>{{item.name}} {{item.flag}} {{item.str}}</p>
    <button (click)='enable(item)'>Display</button><br>
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="item.flag" strokeWidth="3" [diameter]="20"></mat-spinner> 
</div>
```

**TS**

```
names = [
    {
        name: "hello",
        flag: false,
        str: "Arpit"
    },
    ...
];

enable(item) :void {
    item.flag= true;
    ...
}
```

In this way you will have full control on every item of array. If in future you want to customize or manipulate any item, you can do. E.g. you want to toggle on button click.